Best way to argue that $\frac{x^2-1}{2x}$ is invertible
The task is to argue whether the function
$$
f\colon(0,\infty)\to\mathbb{R},\qquad x\longmapsto\frac{x^2-1}{2x}
$$
is invertible.
My question is: What would be the easiest way to argue that it is invertible?
Of course, I can formally show that the function is injective and bijective.
But isn't there a shorter way to argue?
(For example, $f$ is monotonously increasing on $(0,\infty)$. And one can more or less directly see that $\textrm{im}(f)=\mathbb{R}$ because it has a (simple) pole at $x=0$, simple zeros at $x=-1$ and $x=1$ and $f(x)\to\frac{x}{2}$ as $x\to\pm\infty$. But a monotonously increasing or decreasing function $f\colon D\to\textrm{im}(f)$ is bijective and thus invertible. Would that be a reasonable argument?)
In other words: "Look at the graph" of $f$ and one "sees" that it is onto and monotonously increasing...

$f(x)=y$ can be solved explicitly. You get only one solution with $x>0$ for any given $y$. .

Perhaps you should tell us your definition of "invertible". If the function is not surjective (as your last parenthetical remark suggests), then my definition would say that it's not invertible.

Surjective means that the image is equal to the codomain!  In what sense do you believe that the image is not identical to $\mathbb R$?

Ah, sorry. You are right. I was just about to asking if one can immediately see that $\textrm{im}(f)=\mathbb{R}$.

Ok, it has a simple pole at $x=0$ and zeros at $\pm 1$; its asymptote for $x\to\pm\infty$ is $y=x/2$. Hence one can directly see that its image is $\mathbb{R}$ and moreover, that its  monotonously increasing on $(0,\infty)$... hence its invertible...

We have
$$
f'(x) = 1 - \frac{x^2 - 1}{2 x^2} = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{x^2} > 0
$$
We also have
$$
\underset{x \to \infty}{\operatorname{lim}} f(x) = \underset{x \to \infty}{\operatorname{lim}} \frac{x^2 - 1}{2x} = \underset{x \to \infty}{\operatorname{lim}} \frac{x}{2} - \frac{1}{2x} = \infty
$$
and
$$
\underset{x \to 0}{\operatorname{lim}} f(x) = \underset{x \to 0}{\operatorname{lim}} \frac{x^2 - 1}{2x} = \underset{x \to 0}{\operatorname{lim}} \frac{x}{2} - \frac{1}{2x} = -\infty
$$
It is also clear that $f$ is continuous on $(0, \infty)$.
The fact that $f'(x) > 0$ implies that $f$ is injective. Since $f$ is continuous, $\underset{x \to \infty}{\operatorname{lim}} f(x) = \infty$ and $\underset{x \to 0}{\operatorname{lim}} f(x) = -\infty$, $f$ is surjective. Hence $f: (0, \infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ is bijective.

Thanks. I added an argument at the end of my original question. Its a bit similar to your answer. Would you say its a valid argument, say, in an exam?

(+1) You should probably make it clear that you're taking the limit of $\frac{x}{2}-\frac{1}{2x}$ as $x\downarrow0$, i.e. $x$ approaches $0$ from the positive side (otherwise the limit doesn't exist). It's fine when you take the limit of $f(x)$, as $f$ has domain $(0,\infty)$, but when you substitute in the expression it's not entirely clear

Suppose $x\in(0,\infty)$ and let $y=f(x)=\frac{x^2-1}{2x}$. Subtracting by $y$ and multiplying by $2x$ we get the equivalent equation
$$x^2-2yx-1=0.$$
This is a quadratic in $x$, so we can solve for $x$ as
$$x=y\pm\sqrt{y^2+1}.$$
But notice that $x>0$, and
$$y-\sqrt{y^2+1}<y-\sqrt{y^2}=y-\lvert y\rvert\leq0,$$
so we only have the solution
$$x=y+\sqrt{y^2+1}.$$
In particular for any $x\in(0,\infty)$ we can uniquely solve $f(x)=y$, and the above solution works for any $y\in\mathbb R$. Thus we have an inverse $f^{-1}:\mathbb{R}\to(0,\infty)$ given by
$$f^{-1}(y)=y+\sqrt{y^2+1}.$$
